# How to denormalize rows into csv

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
id, name
---------------
1, Customer 01
1, Customer 02
2, Customer 01
3, Customer 01
3, Customer 03
```

Is there an easy way to get result set like so:

```
id, customers
-----------------------
1, [Customer01],[Customer02]
2, [Customer01]
3, [Customer01,[Customer03]
```

I don't really need the brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `for xml path`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
--Create temp table for testing
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Temp

Create table #Temp
            (id Int, 
             name varchar(30))
Insert into #Temp
Values (1, 'Customer 01'),
       (1, 'Customer 02'),
       (2, 'Customer 01'),
       (3, 'Customer 01'),
       (3, 'Customer 03')
```

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        o.id ,
        STUFF((SELECT  ',' + name
               FROM    #Temp AS i
               WHERE   i.ID = o.id
               FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS ConcatenatedName
FROM    #Temp AS o
```

Test is here [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07975c/18)